# Include one CSS rule in another without @extend or @mixin

Tags: sass

I have a rule:

```
 .foo { ...}
```

Later, I want to include this in another rule:

```
 .bar { <want contents of .foo here> }
```

I could do this with @extend, but some consider this [a bad practice](http://www.sitepoint.com/avoid-sass-extend/). I can do it with @include, but now I have to turn .foo into a mixin, which means its no longer shows up as a rule in my stylesheet unless I write the following boilerplate:

```
@mixin foo { ... }
.foo { @include foo(); }
```

I have hundreds of classes that this potentially applies to, and I don't want all that boilerplate. I just want the freedom to include one rule in another rule without first making it a mixin nor dealing with the semantics of @extend (i.e. shared selector).

Is that possible with SASS?

Answer (score 3):

This does exist. You should use a [placeholder selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders) here.

Extending `.foo` is bad because if you later make a rule like `.baz .foo` then anywhere you extend `.foo`, that other two class selector will be extended as well.

If you instead write the first rule as

```
.foo,
%foo { font-family: 'foo' }
```

then you can do whatever you want with `.foo` worry free. When you want something to use the styles in that rule, instead `@extend %foo`. The placeholder selector is not compiled into your CSS and if you never write it into another selector that'll only extend that simpler rule.

If we add

```
.foo.baz { font-size: $baz }
.bar { @extend %foo }
```

You'll nicely compile to

```
.foo, .bar { font-family: 'foo' }
.foo.baz { font-size: $baz }
```

So you are writing a few more characters, but it's not a whole new "rule" like a mixin and you can then safely extend the rule to your heart's content.

Extends can still get out of hand, so still use these carefully and thoughtfully. I wrote [a blog post on this earlier this year](http://alexbea.com/2016/01/10/sass-extends.html) that might help as well.

---

**side comment:**
If this would really be to apply to hundreds of other classes, it might be better to keep `.foo` simple and have as a utility class. Then you'd add `.foo` in your markup where you were thinking of extending it. It's hard to say if that'd be better in your case without details, but it's worth considering. Especially if the rule does something simple but reusable like centering text.

Comment: Did you read the part where the OP doesn't want to use extends?

Comment: I read that he understood it to be bad practice and thus seemed turned of due to that and the perspective of the linked article. I don't think it is bad practice if used carefully and with placeholder selectors, which are in the Sass documentation. My linked post explains more of that.

You should know I've read a few of your comments this morning and you come of as really harsh and discouraging for people newer to contributing to SO. I'm guessing you won't care and it'll be my fault for not understanding SO or something. Here's to trying to help people. Cheers.

Comment: Cool. I did my best to help and if OP doesn't think my answer is right they're under no obligation to accept it. But I'll let that process work out. I'll encourage you to work on [being welcoming, being patient, and assuming good intentions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) going forward.